# Find all possible combinations of different lists with Different lengths of output lists in Python(NOT a Duplicate)

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

I have been trying to find all the combinations of elements in different lists.

I tried with itertools.product() but I get output lists of fixed length

```
 import itertools
 a=[2,4,6,8,10]
 b=[3,6,9]
 c=[5,10]
 d=[10]
 l=list(itertools.product(a,b,c,d))
 print(l)
 [(2, 3, 5, 10), (2, 3, 10, 10), (2, 6, 5, 10), (2, 6, 10, 10), (2, 9, 5, 10), (2, 9, 10, 10), (4, 3, 5, 10), (4, 3, 10, 10), (4, 6, 5, 10), (4, 6, 10, 10), (4, 9, 5, 10), (4, 9, 10, 10), (6, 3, 5, 10), (6, 3, 10, 10), (6, 6, 5, 10), (6, 6, 10, 10), (6, 9, 5, 10), (6, 9, 10, 10), (8, 3, 5, 10), (8, 3, 10, 10), (8, 6, 5, 10), (8, 6, 10, 10), (8, 9, 5, 10), (8, 9, 10, 10), (10, 3, 5, 10), (10, 3, 10, 10), (10, 6, 5, 10), (10, 6, 10, 10), (10, 9, 5, 10), (10, 9, 10, 10)]
```

But what i need is output of lists with different lengths and combinations like

```
      Expected output : [2,3,5,10],
                        [2,3,5],
                        [2,3,10],
                        [2,3,10,10], 
                        [2,3],
                        [2,6,5,10],
                        [2,6,10,10],
                        [2,6,5],
                        [2,6],
                        [2,9,5,10],
                        [2,9,5],
                        [2,9],
                        [2,9,10,10],
                        [4,3,5,10],
                        [4,3,5],
                        [4,3,10,10],
                        .
                        .     
                        [10,9,10,10]
                        ...so on
```

I tried using combinations by combining all the lists but it didn't give the required output

```
a=[2,4,6,8,10,3,6,9,5,10]
import itertools
for i in range(1,4):
     b=list(itertools.combinations(a,i))
     print(b)
```

Given that **you do not know how many lists you will get as an input** So what might be the efficient way to achieve the expected output?

Comment: is the union of `list(itertools.product(a,b))`, `list(itertools.product(a,b,c))`, and `list(itertools.product(a,b,c,d))` what you're after?

Comment: in this case I know there are only four lists. what will be the solution if you do not know how many lists you get?

Comment: You could add a `None` value to each list as a marker for ‘no selection from this list’. Then use `itertools.product(*list_of_lists)`, then strip out the `None` values from the results.

Comment: @Matthias, ahead of you ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is to select either one element or none from each list, right? So append `None` (or any other non-occurring value) to each list, run `itertools.product()`, and strip `None` from each of the results. Done.

```
>>> raw = itertools.product(a+[None], b+[None], c+[None])
>>> clean = [ [ e for e in result if e is not None ] for result in raw ]
>>> clean[:10]
[[2, 3, 10], [2, 3], [2, 6, 5], [2, 6, 10], [2, 6], [2, 9, 5], [2, 9, 10], [2, 9], 
[2, 5], [2, 10]]
```

Comment: But the combinations like [4,3,5,10]..etc is missing right? and isn't [2,10,10] also a combination? 10's  from c and d list. i mean just curious what if we want it like this way

Comment: The 4-way combinations are missing because I only used three lists in the demo. And I only printed out the first 10 results, there are plenty more in `clean`. It's your question, try out the solution before you criticise it...

Comment: You may also need to deduplicate the results, since there could be duplicates after stripping the None’s. That could be done with `sorted(set(clean))`.

Comment: @Matthias, good point. Duplicates will arise not because of the `None`s per se, but because either `a` or `c` could contribute a `[10]`, for example.

Comment: Actually it is because of the Nones. Without them, `product` wouldn’t produce any duplicates since the input lists don’t contain any duplicates within themselves. But with the Nones, (2, 3, None, 10) and (2, 3, 10, None) will both convert to (2, 3, 10).

Comment: By the way, a more general way to do this, that will work even if the lists contain `None` (or anything else), would be to add a line at the start `sentinel = object()`, then replace `None` with `sentinel` everywhere.

Comment: If there's really no reserved value, I would turn each real element into a tuple `(<element>, True)`, then add `(None, False)` ... or `("drop me", False)`, and filter by the second element of the tuple. But it's clearly overkill in this case.